# Optional protocol conforming for iOS classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, protocols

I have a class in my iOS app project that conforms to a certain protocol like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <aProtocol>
```

And at some time in the app I want this certain class to stop conforming to this very protocol. And then bring it back again.

Is there any way in `obj-c` where a class has some optional protocols? How is this controlled?

Comment: You can't stop conforming to a protocol. You can return different values from the protocols depending on state, but you can't physically remove the protocol from the class.

A better description of the underlying problem you are trying to solve should move us into reaching a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove a protocol from the conforming class and bring it back again later. But you can always decide right at the design time whether the protocol has to be optional or required with the help of `@optional` and `@required` keywords. If you are thinking about using a definite protocol method in need, you can try delegation design pattern. The concerned delegate object may conform to the required protocol. And the delegating object may use this delegate in need.